# Can ARKit tracking be as effective as Vuforia's Area targets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, realitykit

`Area Targets` in Vuforia do a great job of matching a LiDAR scan to the room it was scanned in.

Would I be able to use the point cloud scans from the iPad to do the same in RealityKit on a 1 to 1 scale as does Vuforia?

"Underscore 1 to 1".

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea that Vuforia Engine can do both scaning and tracking on LiDAR enabled devices?

Comment: If you are asking if you can scan with the same device you will use to track I think the answer is Yes.  As far as simultaneously, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuforia [Area Target](https://library.vuforia.com/features/environments/area-targets.html) supports scans made with RealityKit-enabled devices with LiDAR Scanner.

So an answer is obvious: **Yes, you can**.

Comment: Is the area target technology of Vuforia my best choice for room scale augmented reality? At times the tracking seems drift or timeout

Comment: Yes, Vuforia's area target is the needed choice in your case! What device are you using?

Comment: At the moment using an iphone 11 pro

Comment: So, if you're using iPhone 11 without LiDAR, a tracking's drift may occur more frequently than expected. That's because you need physically move in a room. LiDAR allows you not move when tracking.

Comment: a modest amount of drift is ok, i am concerned when the whole scene disappears from camera view and takes a moment to reappear.  Still testing though, I am new to the process and may not be set up correctly.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea that Vuforia Engine can do both scaning and tracking on LiDAR enabled devices?

Comment: Hi @Randi, what's your question about?

Comment: @AndyFedoroff I need to create an app which can scan 3D models or Room and need to upload them to Autodesk Forge viewer. So I was looking for 2 SDKs Vuforia Engine and Structure SDK for iOS(https://structure.io/developers). By looking at vuforia documents what I understood was Vuforia is only supporting for tracking. Can we scan the area using Vuforia engine and then use the model on the same app for tracking like their Vuforia Area Target Creator app? Do they expose scanning functionality as well through their SDK?

Comment: I don't want to use 2 apps to achieve my target(scan using vuforia area target creator and import that model into my app and use for tracking)

Comment: Hi @Randi, As far as I know Vuforia does support LiDAR scanning, but I don't have Vuforia in my AR arsenal, so I don't know how to implement its scanning capabilities.